# how to remove a class of character from the string in oracle sql

Tags: oracle11g

I would like to remove the below illegal list of characters from the string in oracle sql.  If the given string has any of these occurrence one or more times.

I need to replace them with space.

```
•   Double quotes( “ )
•   Semi-colon ( ; )
•   Plus sign ( + )
•   Square brackets ( [ ] )
•   Backslash ( \ )
•   Vertical Bar ( | )
•   Greater Than (>)
•   Less Than (<)
```

How do i use the *REGEXP_REPLACE* for this?

I was thinking to use something like

```
  select REGEXP_REPLACE('<stack>>||\[]flow[]+"";' , [[:";\+\[\]\\|><:]],''')
   from dual;
```

However, not sure how to make the user defined character class.

Answer (score 0):

Why use a `regexp` function when a standard Oracle function will do?

```
translate (mystring, 'x";+[]\|><', 'x')
```

The 'x' is there because `translate` doesn't work so well with an empty replacement string!